# Error: Internal Query Processor Error: The query processor encountered an unexpected error during execution (HRESULT = 0x80040e19)

Tags: sql-server-2012

Please help me out with the solution.

When i try to execute the Update Command, I am getting the following error. I am using SQL Server 2012.

`UPDATE WorkOrder SET Delivered = GETDATE() WHERE WONumber= 69375`

> Error: Internal Query Processor Error: The query processor encountered an unexpected error during execution (HRESULT = 0x80040e19)

Answer (score 1):

In my issue with the same error, while running a DBCC checkdb command through SQL, I found issues with a few Tables.
I had to place the database in Single_User Mode, 
run the – `DBCC CHECKDB (‘xxxx’,REPAIR_REBUILD);` – 
(note: the ‘xxxx’ is the database name),
then place the database back in Multi_User Mode.
This resolved the issue for my Client.